# Как импортировать type definition в Angular-проект?

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular, angular5

Подключил из npm types для яндекс-карт: `"@types/yandex-maps": "^2.1.6"`
в `tsconfig` путь указан к ним (другие types работают норм):

```
"typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
```

Импортирую в компонент, чтобы использовать этот namespace (например: `private map: ymaps.Map`), таким образом:

```
import * as ymaps from "yandex-maps";
```

В итоге не компилируется, ругается на строку с импортом:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'yandex-maps' in
>   '/project/components/ya-maps/y-map'

В чем проблема?

Comment: явно укажи в `tsconfig.app.json > types: ["yandex-maps"]`

Comment: @overthesanity это не дало никакого результата

Comment: значит ты что-то делаешь не так, ибо просто со стороны невозможно сказать почему именно эти объявления не подтягиваются компилятором. Я специально установил этот пакет себе и объявления типов - у меня все работает

Comment: подожди, подожди, а почему ты используешь пакет `yandex-maps`, а не `ymaps`?

Comment: @overthesanity с `ymaps` тоже самое - Module not found. Только ymaps и в IDE даже говорит что ошибка, а `yandex-maps` норм, но `yandex-maps` не видит компилятор

Comment: так его он и не увидит, потому что самого пакета `yandex-maps` не существует)

Comment: @overthesanity а ты этот пакет пробовал? https://ibb.co/S7LKRdW  Откуда там `ymaps`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/yandex-maps

Comment: я попробовал `@types/yandex-maps` и он косвенно связан с `ymaps`, я так понял они не смогли их совместить вместе. То есть мы можешь спокойно использовать пространство `ymaps`, только вот сам пакет `ymaps` не видит определения

Answer (score 0):

Если собирать Webpack-ом, необходимо в конфиг добавить

```
externals: {
    "yandex-maps": "ymaps",
},
```